# Torah verse on headstone?

Tags: death, cemetery-grave

Is there any prohibition or reason not to include a Torah verse on a headstone in a Jewish cemetery. I was told its better not to include the whole psuk but just part of it but even that person that told me said that might just be hearsay.

Sourced answers only.

Comment: My rabbi told me specifically to put a pasuk from Shmuel 1 on my father's headstone

Comment: http://shut.moreshet.co.il/shut2.asp?id=100992 האם מותר לכתוב פסוקים על גבי מצבתו של הנפטר...